# How to run non-parallel in more than one process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, parallel-testing

I am using `parallel_tests` gem and more specifically `parallel_rspec`. I have 2 sets of tests that can't run in parallel as they interfere with the state of some other tests.

Currently I am doing 
`parallel_rspec spec --single 'spec/set_A'`

I now have the need to also run `set_B` non-parallely but how do I ensure that it runs in its own process and not with `set_A's` process above?

I have tried `parallel_rspec spec --single 'spec/set_A|set_B'` but it runs both sets in a single process which makes that process run for a really long time. Passing to separate `--single` flags also doesn't seem to achieve that.

Comment: *"I have 2 sets of tests that can't run in parallel as they interfere with the state of some other tests"* -- Can you elaborate on this point? Ideally, the best solution would be to simply change these tests to that they don't interfere with one another!

Comment: I'm not clear whether running the tests in different processes would even solve the problem... (And so I'm concerned you may be asking an XY problem)

Comment: @TomLord these are end to end tests. Test 1 goes to a school page and checks that a report is displayed with correct data for all students. Test 2 requires some students to be removed from the school and then go to the same page and check that the correct report is displayed for the remaining students. If these 2 tests are running at the same time and against the same school then the state of the report can't  be determined. Keeping these tests within a single process to ensure that they run one after the other and between each test the state of the school will be reset.

Comment: A better solution, Rahul, is to run each each process **with a different database**. As you will see in [the `parallel_tests` README](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests#setup-for-rails), it is recommended to define your test database name with `<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>` for precisely this reason.

Comment: Each process uses a unique database. So for example if you run 10 processes then there will be 10 databases. Schools being added/edited/deleted within one process do not affect the other processes.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord. Unfortunately I am testing end to end on an application that uses CosmosDB and I am not using a rails setup. I am not sure I have the option of doing what you are suggesting. It's not a test databased that I control.

Comment: Oh...yeah, that makes things difficult. Again, I could ask "why can't you be in control of the *test* database?", but I don't want to go down a rabbit hole here. You're going to hit all sorts of problems running tests against a third party, online database that you're not in control of. (For example, what happens when a second developer joins the project, and you try running tests at the same time??)

Comment: Taking [a quick glance at the source code](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/blob/06656a00f5a18a5703e7728ed8614827d3ec0409/lib/parallel_tests/cli.rb#L186), I think you can just supply multiple `--single` options?? I.e. `parallel_rspec spec --single 'spec/set_A' --single 'spec/set_B'`?

Comment: Yep that's the first thing I tried. Even if I supply multiple --single flags it clubs all of those together in a single process not separate single processes. This is my actual question.

Comment: `--isolate`? I'm just going off the README here.

Comment: Yeah, that just ensures that no other tests are run in that single process. It doesn't affect the tests that actually go in the process in the first place